# Matplotlib.pyplot import err "undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsASCIIString"

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am on wheezy and received the following error while importing matplotlib.pyplot as plt.

Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb 25 2016, 15:41:12) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import matplotlib.pyplot
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 29, in 
> > >           import matplotlib.colorbar
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 32, in 
> > >           import matplotlib.artist as martist
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 14, in 
> > >           from .transforms import (Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox,
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 39, in 
> > >           from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
> > >       ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsASCIIString

I looked around but could not find the solution. Any help will be appreciated.